# Applying network diffusion to a graph created with the igraph library in R

Tags: r, rstudio, graph-neural-network

I have created a graph using the igraph library.

```
library(igraph)
transactions <- readRDS("transactions.rds")
nodes <- readRDS("nodes.rds")

g<-graph_from_data_frame(d=transactions,vertices = nodes,directed = T)
```

I am using the subset of the original database which I have stored here https://github.com/leonelparrales22/NetworkDiffusion

What I want to know is, when stimulating a node in the network, what is the impact it is going to generate by infecting neighboring nodes.

For example, what is the percentage of the network that will be affected if I stimulate node X?

I would like to make a simulation or know what metrics can help to realize something like the following image:

[image]

I was trying with this library,
[netdiffuseR](https://github.com/USCCANA/netdiffuseR)
But it asks for a TOA argument, which I don't understand very well what it refers to. And I don't know if I can calculate it or it is something that had to have been previously collected.

Comment: From reference provided by you: toa <- sample(c(1:(1+nper-1), NA), n, TRUE)
head(toa)